# Issues installing VMware Player on macOS

Tags: macos, installation, vmware, vmware-player

I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 and I am trying to install VMware Player, but when I run the command

```
chmod a+x VMware-Player-14.1.2-8497320.x86_64.bundle
```

and

```
sudo ./VMware-Player-14.1.2-8497320.x86_64.bundle
```

I get

```
stat: illegal option -- -
usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]
```

Not sure what to do, because I don't know any other way to turn this file into an executable to get it onto my computer.

Answer (score 1):

This script does not work because [**VMware Player**](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player.html) is not available for macOS. The script you're using has probably been written for Linux.

If you want to create VMware virtual machines on macOS, you can use [**VMware Fusion**](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html).

Comment: awesome. Thanks for your answer. Is the installation process the same for that

Comment: @Fibonac7 The installation process is similar to a lot of macOS applications. You download a `.dmg` file, open it & you have an installer app inside.